# Odd draw behavior

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

In my xna game, I have a method to create the treasure chests in random locations on the map. The thing is, it draws them all in the same place. The random doesn't generate unique random numbers for the v3 points. However, if I debug and step through the method, it works perfectly.

```
void CreateTreasure()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            Treasure t = new Treasure(new Vector3((float)random.Next(0, 600), 0, (float)random.Next(600)));
            treasureList.Add(t);
        }
    }
```

and in the draw I loop through

```
foreach (Treasure t in treasureList)
        {
            DrawModel(treasure, Matrix.Identity * Matrix.CreateScale(0.02f) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(t.Position));
            PositionOnMap(ref t.Position);
        }
```

PositionOnMap just takes the position and adjusts the Y to make models sit on the heightmap. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create the random outside your loop and only use next inside, also use random seed for the initializer like:

```
var random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
```

Comment: Seeing 'new' inside a loop is always something to be wary of. Usually because of memory issues though.

Comment: You absolutely should **not** be initialising `Random` like that! Use the default constructor unless you actually have proper need for a seeded random number generator. Seeding it to the hash of a GUID is a terrible idea.

Comment: your argument is lacking any supporting facts, please elaborate with constructive reasoning or withdraw the objection

Comment: Perhaps *you'd* care to elaborate why it's there at all? To me it seems indicative of extremely poor coding practice: As if you've noticed that creating more than one `Random` per millisecond is giving you identical sequences, and have just shoved **something** in to fix it without understanding the problem, which is: you shouldn't be creating so many instances of `Random` in the first place!

Comment: (I see you're a "web guy" - and I can *perhaps* see a use-case for this if you're having to instance a RNG for each request *and* avoid collisions, at least at the same instant. But this would be a very specific, targeted hack that should be treated as such.)

Comment: I agree, it is an overkill using new GUID hash for seed, but it is not "absolutely" wrong or "extremely poor coding", perhaps the default constructor would suffice; I also do use one instance of Random for the entire game/application, but only if it is a single thread

Answer (score 2):

You need to move Random outside of your loop.  Right now, it will create a new Random instance each time.  Since the default seed is time based, if this occurs quickly, the first call to Next() will always return the same value.  Try this:

```
void CreateTreasure()
{
    // Just move this outside, so each .Next call is on the same instance...
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Treasure t = new Treasure(new Vector3((float)random.Next(0, 600), 0, (float)random.Next(600)));
        treasureList.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or better yet - just create one instance of `Random` and use that throughout your game.